# Does Python's 'in' operator for lists have an early-out for successful searches

Tags: python, list, search, containers, python-internals

If i have a list then i look up a element in list by:

```
alist=[ele1, ele2, ele3, ele4,ele5,...]
if ele3 in alist:
  print "found"
```

Will in stop a search from alist at ele3 ?
Or it will run though all remaining element to the end.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Implementation defined, I suppose; but it would have to be a pretty brain-dead implementation not to return early.

Comment: This *is not* a duplicate of the suggested question. That question asks for the time complexity, but that doesn’t help, since no matter whether Python exits early, the worst-case complexity is O(n); knowing that it’s O(n) doesn’t tell you anything about whether Python exits early.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Will in stop a search from alist at ele3 ?

Yes, the *in* operator on a list does a linear search with an **early exit** if the target is found.  Also, it will by-pass the final comparison if the target object is identical to the object in the list.

Here's some tracer code that proves the result by making the comparisons visible:

```
class Int(int):
    'Make comparisons visible'
    def __cmp__(self, other):
        print 'Comparing %s to %d' % (self, other)
        return int.__cmp__(self, other)

ele1 = Int(1)
ele2 = Int(2)
ele3 = Int(3)
ele4 = Int(4)
ele5 = Int(5)

alist = [ele1, ele2, ele3, ele4, ele5]
if ele3 in alist:
  print "found"
```

The output is:

```
Comparing 3 to 1
Comparing 3 to 2
found
```

Python translates the *in* operator in the expression `ele3 in alist` into a [magic method call](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#not-in) such as `alist.__contains__(ele3)`.   The [*list.__contains__()*](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/17e1af9ad66c/Objects/listobject.c#l437) method works like this:

```
def __contains__(self, target):
    for element in self:
        if target is element or target == element:
            return True
    return False
```

Hope this makes the process crystal clear :-)

Answer (score 2):

`in` stop searching the list once it finds the item.

[Source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a36d469f31c1/Objects/listobject.c#l402)

Comment: You could stand to have [a source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a36d469f31c1/Objects/listobject.c#l402) for that claim.

Answer (score 1):

Your purpose of the condition `if ele3 in alist:` is, **check `ele3` exist in alist or not**. Once it finds then there is no need to process other element.

Like if you have condition

```
False and True
```

if the first element is `False` then there is no need to process rest statement. Because what ever remaining statement is it will be always `False`.

Same rule apply to your condition, once find then there is no need to process other element.

Answer (score 1):

Basically 'In' operator works just like this function:

```
def IsInEnumerable(element, enumerable):
    for e in enumerable:
        if e == element:
            return True

    return False

IsInEnumerable('test', ['foo', 'test', 'bar', 'meow', 'quack']) # True
```

As you see, there will be only two iterations of 'for' loop. Same is true when using 'in' operator.